# Why theology plays a great role in becoming great mathematicians?

Tags: biographical-details, mathematicians

Why theology play a great role  in  becoming  great mathematicians?

I have some confusion about theology with mathematics.

I read the biography of Euler and Bernhard Riemann.

Both were studying theology in order to become a pastor, and after that they become great mathematicians.

Even if you see the  other great mathematicians like Blaise pascal, Newton etc they all studied theology.

Comment: The only thing that plays a great role in becoming a great mathematician is choosing one's ancestors wisely.

Comment: Why do you think that a couple of mathematicians with interest in theology allows us to conclude that "theology play a great role in becoming great mathematicians"?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA..... 90%  mathematician are theologian in 16-19th century

Comment: On the basis of what "statistical data" are you asserting that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An historian could tell the tale more fully but back before Galileo and Newton there were no sciences to speak of. There was medicine of Galen from even further back. The practice of using Greek logic to solve mysteries of nature was not yet popular, at least in Europe.

The major form of scholarship there was of the Bible and histories. Anyone whose abilities were more intellectual than physical would tend to move in that direction. This would invite them to become theologians of some repute, or related professions, before their other interests in matters as novel as science started to be of some value.  The Church kept intellectuals and intellectualism alive for centuries, even up into the 19th century.

In earlier days European mathematics had crept along with much the same surroundings as Cardano could tell you.

I look forward to informative if scathing corrections.

Comment: Not very clear the connection with the question... Euler and Riemann were **not** "before Galileo and Newton".